# PHP MySQL Drop Down Box Populate Selected Value

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have read tutorials about how to populate an entire Drop down list with MySQL, but the problem I am running into is that I only want to grab the one from the database and have that be the selected one. So I would have like a drop down with three items (Item1, Item2, Item3) in the database its stored in a column called itemschoice which has a value of 'Item2'. How do I go about getting item2 to be selected when I load the drop down box?

Comment: i think AJAX solution will work very well !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `<option>` element add the `selected` attribute for the value that is in `itemschoice`.

Crude example using a made up function to get the choice:

```
$choice = get_items_choice();
$results = mysqli_query($sql);

echo '<select name="whatever">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if ($row['choice'] === $choice) {
        echo '<option value="' . $choice . '" selected="selected" />';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $choice . '" />';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

This is just an example, don't copy & paste this without adding some kind of error verification!

Comment: I thought of that but consider this `<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
  <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
  <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
</select>`
If I replaced the Selected one with PHP code then Item2 would appear twice in the list.

Comment: @JosephD See my edit adding the code example.  You should be able to get your list with the specific one selected without adding duplicate entries.