# sql populated drop down to include database value

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to populate a select drop down with all entries from the database but stuck where the already set value is not able to show or shows as a duplicate. i searched on here and found two similar questions but their answers did not help me. my code below

connect.php is included which has all the database connect information

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM experts", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
?>


<select name="expert" id="expert">
<option value="<?php echo $row['expert']; ?>"><?php echo $row['expert']; ?> </option>


<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['expert']."'>".$row['expert']."</option>";
}
?>

</select>
```

the problem with this is it includes a duplicate entry as well as the selected entry. i know i need to add an if statement to remove the selected entry but not sure how.

[PHP MySQL Drop Down Box Populate Selected Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725263/php-mysql-drop-down-box-populate-selected-value) seems to have my answer but i don't seem to be able to use the example to suit my code as its worded differently.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. **They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)**. Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $row['expert']; ?>">...` is outside the loop in the first one, however I don't see the need for it.

Comment: Jay. I learned that too late but i have invested far too much time and effort that changing my code to PDO or MySQLi will not be the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: fred. i understand that, but if i remove that line it doesn't take the currently selected database value

Comment: I find that rather strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="expert" id="expert">
    <!-- Show an empty option so the "default" is blank -->
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    // Define the desired selected value from the database (if any)
    $selected_value = CODE_TO_GET_CURRENT_VALUE;
    // Loop through all of the available options to create your... well, options
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        // If this option matches the one you want to select, add the HTML "selected" attribute
        $selected = ($row['expert'] == $selected_value ) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $row['expert'] . "'" . $selected . ">" . $row['expert'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: im gonna try this out.

Comment: how do i define the default value. is this when there is none selected or the one already in the database.

Comment: That would be a value already in the database. If there's no value in the db, just return `false` or `null` for `$default_value`, then it will never match `$row['expert']` and no options will be marked as `selected`.

Comment: ok i think its working with this code - no duplicates

<select name="expert" id="expert">
    <?php
    // First, define the desired default value
    $default_value = $row['expert'];
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $selected = ($row['expert'] == $default_value) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $row['expert'] . "'" . $selected . ">" . $row['expert'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>

but now i need to include a null object. would i just add a select option outside the loop or is there another way.

Comment: excellent works like a charm although i don't understand why it works. maybe you can just quickly break it down for me. i have already marked your answer as correct

Comment: @SaudKazia added some comments to try to clear things up. Sorry it wasn't clear in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `<option>` that is out of the while loop. 
That's why your first item is duplicated.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM experts", $con);

    if(!$qry)
    {
        die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
    }
?>

<select name="expert" id="expert">
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['expert']."'>".$row['expert']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: That's what I said but OP says *"fred. i understand that, but if i remove that line it doesn't take the currently selected database value"*.

Comment: Yeah, i saw your comment after i posted the answer. Although OP didn't mention the need to get the selected option in the problem description.